# CRM Dynamics 2015: Conditionally updating a field in CRM using Scribe

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, scribe-workbench

We are using scribe to migrate data from a source into CRM 2015 Online. The DTS will run every 15 mins. Is it possible update the fields in the target based on a condition?

Currently I am following this approach:

```
IF(S1= UserVariables,#NULL!,S1 ).
```

Also  “Allow NULL values to overwrite Target data”  is unchecked. UserVariable is linked to that particular field.

The main reason for trying it this way is to stop the audit logs from building up in CRM if the source value is unchanged.(The client wants auditing ON for everything!). This is not working however. It is skipping the rows! No updates are performed even if the source value is different from target.

I tried `IF(S1= "targetfield",#NULL!,S1 )`, This time the updates are performing even if the `source=target`! Thus building up the audit logs.

Turning off auditing is not an option!
Is there any other way to do this?

**Note: Using scribe insight v.7.7 on-premise.**

Answer (score 0):

I use CozyRock and Kingsway Soft mainly (Kingsway my personal pref), so I'm not 100% on the optimal approach for Scribe.

Anyhow, I normally write these to a staging table and then only update what will change.  So if you:

1. Pulled records from the data source
2. Pulled corresponding records from CRM
3. Compared locally and built a staging table of only what will change
4. Finally update based on staging table records

This approach is typically faster and would not write unnecessary records to the audit log.